# shmget and shmat on array of strings

Tags: c, shared-memory

Ok, so I have an array of srings

```
char array[4][20];

//initialized
strcpy(array[0], "PERSON1");
strcpy(array[1], "PERSON2");
...
```

My question is how would I use shmget, and shmat to turn this array into shared memory?
Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(array),0660 | IPC_CREAT);

char** shared = shmat(segment_id,NULL,0);
```

This is a possible solution.

Comment: could you give me example of how I would perfrom say "strcpy (array[2] = "PERSON3");" but using the shared double pointer to shared memory?

Comment: Since in this situation (I believe) that "shared" is the variable that gains access to the shared memory, but I'm confused on how I would traverse the array (of say 5 items).

Comment: sizeof(array) is 80 so divide shared segment by 4 and then do your work as with the array. Look documentation for memcpy and you 'll see how to use it. A little example: 3th row of array memcpy(array + 2*20, "your data", sizeof("your data"))